# Python to wait up to 100% compete to execute next command

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the output1:

```
server                        destination-path           progress-percent
----------------- ---------------------------------      ----------------
server1            /vol/server1/vol2                      54%
```

output 2:

```
 This table is currently empty.
```

What i need is I need to wait up to it completes 100% or when no out put is exist that is when This table is currently empty.

Below is the code i tried and It does not work. But i want to put here what i tried before posting question here

```
def wait_to_complete(self):
    status = ''
    while not status[2] == "100%" or not status[2] == "" :
        for line in self.get_status.split("\n"): # get_status have output 1 or output 2
            if (re.search(self.vserver_name, line)) and len(line) >= 3:
                status = line.split(" ")
                status = filter(None, status)
```

Comment: You'll get an index error straight away in your while loop.

Comment: Yes exactly I am getting same thing

Comment: At the beginning, you have `status = ''`. Right after, you try to call  status[2]. You try to get 2nd item of NOTHING. What do you think it should return?

Comment: It helps us if you elaborate on "it does not work". The error is pretty obvious in this case (as stated above), but the inclusion of those words usually indicates that the question requires more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here status is initialized with `''` then accessing the second element will give index error;

Try;

```
def wait_to_complete(self):
    while True:
        status = []
        for line in self.get_status.split("\n"): # get_status have output 1 or output 2
            status = filter(None, line.split(" "))
            if self.vserver_name in status: break
        if len(status) > 2 and (status[2] == '100%' or status[2] == ''):
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop in infinite loop and break on condition met

```
def wait_to_complete(self):
    status = ''
    while 1:
        for line in self.get_status.split("\n"):
            if (re.search(self.vserver_name, line)) and len(line) >= 3:
                status = line.split()
                if status[2] == '100%':
                    status = filter(None, status)
                    break
            elif 'This table is currently empty' in line:
                status = 'This table is currently empty'
                break
```